# Setting QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions for QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, pyqgis-3, save, writers

I wrote a processing scrip for QGIS 2.18 to create a multi-distance buffer rings using the haversine formula. Unfortunately, it no longer works after I updated to QGIS 3.4.5. I've tried updating the script wherever I can but I can't figure out how to fix the part of the code where it writes the buffers to a shapefile.

Here's my code:

```py
from math import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

layer = iface.activeLayer()
for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
    geom = feat.geometry()

start_x = geom.asPoint().x()
start_y = geom.asPoint().y()
sides = 64
radius = 6378137.0  # meters

# create layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "Distance Buffers", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()

# changes are only possible when editing the layer
vl.startEditing()

# add fields
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("Distance", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Label", QVariant.String)])

distance = [250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 40000, 50000]
for i in range(len(distance)):
    points = []
    dist = distance[i]
    degrees = 0
    while degrees <= 360:
        degrees = degrees + 360 / sides

        start_lon = start_x * pi / 180
        start_lat = start_y * pi / 180
        bearing = degrees * pi / 180

        end_lat = asin((sin(start_lat) * cos(dist / radius)) + (cos(start_lat) * sin(dist / radius) * cos(bearing)))
        end_lon = start_lon + atan2(sin(bearing) * sin(dist / radius) * cos(start_lat),
                                    cos(dist / radius) - (sin(start_lat) * sin(end_lat)))

        points.append(QgsPointXY(end_lon * 180 / pi, end_lat * 180 / pi))

        fet_name = str(distance[i])
        if distance[i] < 1000:
            label = str(distance[i]) + "m"
        else:
            label = str(distance[i]/1000) + "km"

    # add a feature
    fet = QgsFeature()
    geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points])
    fet.setGeometry(geometry)
    fet.setAttributes([fet_name,label])
    pr.addFeatures([fet])

# commit to stop editing the layer
vl.commitChanges()

# update layer's extent when new features have been added
# because change of extent in provider is not propagated to the layer
vl.updateExtents()

myDir = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")
file_name = 'Distance Buffers' + '.shp'
ShapefileDir = myDir + "/Shapefiles/" + file_name

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vl, ShapefileDir, "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

At the last line of the code I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py",
> line 227, in runAlgorithm exec(self.editor.text(), d) File "", line
> 68, in TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments
> did not match any overloaded call: overload 1: argument 4 has
> unexpected type 'NoneType' overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type
> 'NoneType' overload 3: argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'

Based on the QGIS 3.0 documentation, I think `writeAsVectorFormat` now takes the following arguments: `writeAsVectorFormat(layer: QgsVectorLayer, fileName: str, options: QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions, newFilename: str = ‘’)` but I can't figure out how to set the `SaveVectorOptions`.

Can someone show me how this is done with this script, or with any other working examples?

Comment: Related to your comment "# changes are only possible when editing the layer", this is not true. You are using the `dataProvider`, so you don't need to use `startEditing` and `commitChanges`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it happens, I have just [finished updating](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/pull/3451) the documentation on vector layers. The big change is that you can't pass in `None` as the CRS any longer, so either use an explicit one or leave it out altogether.

You now need something like:

```
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("my_shapes", "UTF-8", driverName="ESRI Shapefile")
```

The [latest docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat) are available which give the full list of parameters.